# I cannot delete a specific commit from git

Tags: git, github, git-bash

I am trying to delete specific commit from git log. I have already visited many asked question and found that `git rebase -i` is the way to go.
But this is not working why?
Below is my screenshot which shows I have 3 commits and I am trying to get rid of **file1.txt**

Here is what I been trying to do:

```
git log --oneline
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

Then notepad opens,
To be clear, here are screen shots:
[image]

Then I add

```
drop <commit-hash of file1.txt>
then save and exit
```

But nothing seems changed !
[image]

How should I delete a specific commit?

And what should I do if that specific commit is already pushed into remote repo?

Comment: You want to remove the first commit?

Comment: You have to tell git to start from right before `file1.txt` : `git rebase -i HEAD~3`

Comment: If the `file1.txt` commit is the first commit in your history, there is a special option : `git rebase -i --root`

Comment: @LeGEC I did tried `git rebase -i HEAD~3`  but it is telling **fatal: invalid upstream 'HEAD~3'**. What this means?

Comment: @LeGEC `git rebase -i --root` worked but let us assume **file.txt** is not the first commit. Suppose it lies in somewhere middle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove a commit using interactive rebase, you must initiate the rebase starting at the *parent* of that commit. That way, the target commit is included in the todo list.

You didn't do that so your target commit wasn't in the todo list. You tried to add it manually but that's bogus.

In the special case where your target has no parent, you can use the --root option. That was the situation you were in.

Finally, note that Git is about commits. Not files.